# Diminishing performance of gdal_polygonize in a python subprocess for GRASS to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgis, gdal, polygonize, subprocess

I have written a python script to polygonize GRASS rasters into a PostgreSQL database using the gdal utility `gdal_polygonize`:

```
sub.call('gdal_polygonize.py -8 gdb/quercus/{0}/cellhd/{1} -f "PostgreSQL\" PG:\"dbname=quercus\" {2}'.format(r,rcRast,pgTableName), shell=True)
```

The command works, however performance seems to drop off as the process proceeds. I am woefully ill-prepared to debug performance issues that may be related to the use of `subprocess`.

Are there any suggestions for a more robust use of subprocess and/or ways of benchmarking the performance?

Comment: does your python install have the gdal library?

Comment: No version information or specs were given. This question is possibly fixed in a newer version.  I would also make a guess that this is more of a performance issue related to PostgreSQL rather than GIS specific.